# Jquery Function for checkbox other option

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form with checkbox only and i have a other option at last. i want to open a text box or textarea on checking others option where user can write his own text.

Comment: Have you tried building such a feature?

Comment: could you show us your code or your attempts???

Comment: ADD some HTML and CSS...

Answer (score 3):

## Solution Using checkboxes

#### Method 1 - create "input" on the fly, remove it when unchecked.

Simple, really. You'd have a checkbox group which looks like this :

```
<h3>Which animal do you like the most?</h3>

<input type="checkbox" value="cats" id="cats" name="animals" class="animals" />
<label for="cats">cats</label>
<br/>
<!--extra checkboxes-->
<input type="checkbox" value="other" id="other" name="animals" class="animals" />
<label for="other">other</label>
```

Then, you'd write a change event for this :

```
$(".animals").change(function () {
    //check if its checked. If checked move inside and check for others value
    if (this.checked && this.value === "other") {
        //add a text box next to it
        $(this).next("label").after("<input id='other-text' placeholder='please enter animal' type='text'/>")
    } else {
        //remove if unchecked
        $("#other-text").remove();
    }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/KqRpM/

#### (better & cleaner) Method 2 - Keep "input" in the DOM, hide/show when checked/unchecked

Your markup would have that extra `<input>`, right after that last `label` :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="other" id="other" name="animals" class="animals" />
<label for="other">other</label>
<input id='other-text' placeholder='please enter animal' type='text' />
```

where the `other-text` is hidden using css at the start :

```
#other-text{
  display: none;
}
```

Then you JS would look like this :

```
$(".animals").change(function () {
    //check if the selected option is others
    if (this.value === "other") {
        //toggle textbox visibility
        $("#other-text").toggle();
    }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/KqRpM/1/

## Solution using radio buttons

But that said, in your case its better if it were a radio button group. Just change the markup from `type=checkbox` to `type=radio`. The JS remains the same as Method 1 checkbox.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/XzaRP/

Comment: How do you get the input value when the form is submitted?